# Where is the IPN/Intuit PayNow Integration Guide

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Does anyone know where is the online guide for `IPN/Intuit PayNow Integration`? I searched a lot but couldnt find one. Here is the current code I have received with an application I am supposed to upgrade:

```
<form action="https://ipn.intuit.com/payNow/start" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="payByIpnForm" method="post">
    <input name="eId" type="hidden" value="{EID KEY}" /> 
    <input name="uuId" type="hidden" value="{UUID KEy}" /> 
    <input type="image" src="images/pay_now_btn.png" style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you looking for the Merchant Services SDK? 
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/030_qbms

Comment: I couldnt find such a simple form in that documentation as implemented in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The form you show here is from a service called Intuit Payment Network (IPN).  This is separate from Intuit merchant Services.  Surely you got the code because you have an IPN account already.  Log in to ipn.intuit.com and the code comes from a tool called ecommerce button (search the page for button).  It's pretty simple, I don't think this supports much customization beyond what they provide in the button configuration GUI.  So I doubt there is any "guide".